# Comment over 600 chars lost v.s. simply display error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, character-limit

Hi, I just lost a comment entry that was over 600 characters long when I attempted to save it.

Granted, I did not pay attention to the visible character limit.  Still, perhaps SO could display a message instead of losing my entry ?

Comment: I agree that this is a bug. But then: 600 characters just for a comment? The world now learns to communicate with 140 char messages (Jeff's beloved twitter, short messages), so this seems so 90ties ;-)

Comment: @Ralph: have you *seen* Jeff's beloved twitter feed? That's not communication, it's a sig file!

Answer (score 6):

I think the best solution would be to just have the text field stop accepting input at 600 characters.

Comment: They tried this once. It was *very* annoying. The bug here is that the Add Comment button still submits after warning you that you're over the limit...

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed and will be in the next build.

I'll refactor that a bit later to follow the same convention that minimum length checks use: disable the submit button if validation isn't met.

Answer (score 4):

It does display a message. Unfortunately, it also reloads the page, losing anything you've written. Note that comment submission normally happens via an AJAX request and does *not* reload the whole page.

**That's** a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Like Thomas said, the system should probably just have that hard limit set. But also, users need to pay attention when the red text starts counting down.